# How to decrypt a symmetrically encrypted OpenPGP message using PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I have an OpenPGP message which looks something like this given to me in a file:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (MingW32)

jA0EAgMCtCzaGHIQXY9g0sBnAeDOQ9GuVA/uICuP+7Z2dnjNCLgRN0J/TzJs1qcW
aJYBTkH5KQCClCxjwTYbHZCox1sENfIS+KxpCKJQqAX3SNEFm0ORNE6RNwEgb1Zj
uOdIw8auxUsjmQKFLAcZIPKjBjyJqSQVfmEoteVn1n+pwm8RdIZevCHwLF2URStB
nBVuycaxcaxcaxcxccxcxacqweqweqwe123fsMqQPaTusOBGpEQrWC9jArtvYEUpY
aNF6BfQ0y2CYrZrmzRoQnmtnVu10PagEuWmVxCucyhVwlthVgN0iBog9jhjliQkc
rrDTupqB4IimMEjElGUHtkuvrCQ0jQnOHEAJmmefMDH0NkYKGd5Ngt21I5ge5tob
/uBjHKMxjNgg1nWfg6Lz4jqoKe/EweuEeg==
=+N9N
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

and was given a 15 character passphrase to decrypt it, I suppose. But I really don't have any idea to decrypt the file using PHP. I take a look at [PHP's GnuPG manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-decrypt.php)  and under the `gnugpg_decrypt()` example it gives this code:

```
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_adddecryptkey($res,"8660281B6051D071D94B5B230549F9DC851566DC","test");
$plain = gnupg_decrypt($res,$encrypted_text);
echo $plain;
```

So taking a look at this function `gnupg_adddecryptkey`, it mentioned I need a fingerprint. What is that actually? And where can I get it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fingerprint is a hash sum calculated on the public key and some meta data like key creation time. It is also returned after importing a key through [`gnupg_import`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-import.php) as `fingerprint` attribute.

This is for public/private key cryptography, which you're seemingly not using: when encrypting with a passphrase, you're omitting the public/private key cryptography part and directly use symmetric encryption for the message, with a session key (sometimes also called cipher block or symmetric key) derived from your passphrase.

Symmetric encryption is not supported by PHP's GnuPG module. There are no functions to perform symmetric decryption, and this limitation is also described in the [module's source documentation](https://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_GPG/docs/latest/Crypt_GPG/Crypt_GPG.html):

> This class provides an object oriented interface to GNU Privacy Guard (GPG).
>
> Though GPG can support symmetric-key cryptography, this class is intended only to facilitate public-key cryptography.

You will have to perform decryption manually by calling `gpg`. An example command line would be

```
gpg --symmetric --decrypt [file]
```

(alternatively, you can also provide the input through STDIN). For handing over the passphrase, have a look at GnuPG's `--passphrase...` options:

> **`--passphrase-fd n`**
>
> Read  the  passphrase from file descriptor n. Only the first line will be read from file descriptor n. If you use 0 for n, the passphrase will be read from STDIN. This can
>    only be used if only one passphrase is supplied.
>
> **`--passphrase-file file`**
>
> Read the passphrase from file file. Only the first line will be read from file file. This can only be used if only one passphrase  is  supplied.  Obviously,  a  passphrase
>   stored in a file is of questionable security if other users can read this file. Don't use this option if you can avoid it.
>
> **`--passphrase string`**
>
> Use  string as the passphrase. This can only be used if only one passphrase is supplied. Obviously, this is of very questionable security on a multi-user system. Don't use
>   this option if you can avoid it.

Be aware that all other users of a computer can read all other user's command line arguments, so especially for shared hosting platforms, `--passphrase` is a definite no-go.

Comment: Very informative. Learned something new today. Thanks!

Comment: I got `gpg: conflicting commands` when passing --symmetric and --decrypt.  Just the latter was needed, for me, today.  My file was definitely encrypted with --symmetric.  I thought it was my socks but perhaps that smell is coming from my aging gpg 1.4.18.

Comment: `--symmetric` is not an option for either `--encrypt` or `--decrypt`, but a command for _symmetric encryption_. The message contains information that it is encrypted symmetrically in its meta data, so a simple `--decrypt` is sufficient.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is compatible with not just PHP, but GnuGPG in general. To summarize Jens Erat's answer and adding the encryption step for anyone else who comes across this question, here's a solution, assuming a file exists called `passwords.txt`:

```
// encrypt
gpg --output passwords.gpg --symmetric passwords.txt
// decrypt
gpg —decrypt  passwords.gpg
```

Comment: Haven't tried this for files but doesn't work for a directory. First command gives `can't open '<directory-name>'` and second one gives `conflicting commands`.

Comment: Good to know. Works for files. Feel free to suggest an extension that works for both!